# Remove message for whole session with button?

Tags: javascript, android, css

I am using the code below to show a message when a mobile device (smartphone or tablet) is in portrait mode. This works fine!

However, I need code that when the user clicks on the X-button, the message does not appear anymore as long as ANY of the pages of the website are being visited in that session.

But if the website is closed; at the next visit the message should appear again when the website is viewed in portrait mode.

How can this be done?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
}

#warning-message {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  #warning-message {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  #warning-message {
    display: none;
  }
}

#landscape-button {
  background-color: #2A3847;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
Please open in "full page" mode and scale your window to a portrait size to see the message appear.<br><br>
<div id="warning-message" style="position:fixed; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; z-index: 99999999; background-color: #2A3847; width: 90vw; min-height: 90vh; text-align:center; padding:25px 15px 35px 15px; right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;">
  <button type="button" id="landscape-button">X</button>
  <p style="font-size: 1.3em; color: #ffffff; positie:absolute; text-align:center;"><span style="margin: 0 0 0 25px; text-align:center; font-size: 2em; letter-spacing: -0.04em;">please rotate your screen</span><br><br>This website is best viewed in landscape mode. So please, rotate your mobile device, and if activated also disable
    your screen rotation lock. If you prefer to remain in portrait mode, ignore this message and close it at the "x".</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should go with cookie.

Comment: How would I do this, @Nirav Joshi. And what if user has cookies turned off?

Comment: than you can use session.

Comment: I do not know how you mean (?)

Comment: Look if you want to achieve than than you have to store data some where like `sessions` if user clicks on that button than you have to set `session`.and for display it you have to check that `session` is exists or not. if exists than don't show `message`. if not than show it. that's it. if it is android technology than i don't know how to create `sessions` in android. hope you will get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what works, taking into account that the session storage only starts after the "X" button is clicked. So even if the page is reloaded before the close button "X" is clicked, the message will still appear when the window is sized to portrait mode or if the mobile device is held in portrait mode. After the "X" button is clicked, the message will no longer appear upon reload of the page within the same session.

[**See the example here!**](https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/56/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('isfirst');
    if (data == undefined) {
        $("#warning-message").addClass("shown-modal");
    } else {
        $("#warning-message").hide();
    }
});
//close the pop
$("#landscape-button").on('click', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('isfirst', 'true');
    $("#warning-message").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use sessionStorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

When user clicks "X":

```
sessionStorage.setItem('closed', 'true');
```

When re-loading the page:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
if (data == 'true') {
    // do nothing
} else {
    // display block
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Lauren G! Sorry my response is late. I will try to implement your answer in my code.

Comment: No worries! What are you seeing now? Do you know if your js code setting and getting the sessionStorage variable is working, or are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: could you please have a look here, @ Lauren G, and see if you can help me get it working.  https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/8/

Comment: @Eddy -

Issue 1: Line 1 of JS uses '.warning-message' instead of '#warning-message' (though I'm assuming you actually meant to trigger on clicking '#landscape-button', not the whole div).

Issue 2: (I'm assuming) you want to check the state of the token before even loading the pop-up. This is best handled within jQuery's `$( document ).ready(function() { });

The .on(click) only needs to hide the div; everything else can be handled in the docready function. On docready, if 'isfirst' doesn't exist, load popup and save 'isfirst'. Else, don't show popup.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, @Lauren G! I believe I am now doing things as you described, I hope. https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/16/ However, it is still not working. Even clicking the button does not close the message. Sorry to ask you for more help again, but I am just not getting there on my own.

Comment: No worries! It looks like your only problem is a few extra {brackets}.

1. Remove your brackets around your sessionStorage.setItem (so the open bracket on line 4, and closed bracket on line 6).

2. You've got an extra curly bracket on Line 14. The .on function opens a single curly bracket but you have two closing curly brackets (Line 14, and Line 15).

Comment: where should they be or taken off? can you adjust here and update it: jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/16

Comment: Sorry about that - I hit "enter" before finishing typing :) Previous comment edited!

Comment: please see here for my changes, Lauren https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/19/ But it still it does not work. Even the message doesn't close when clicking on the button.

Comment: My bad - I tweaked the jsfiddle but forgot to mention one major change - jQuery! On your site, you'll need to import the jQuery min file; on jsfiddle.net, you can click "Javascript" and, on the dropdown, select "jQuery 3.2.1" under "FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS". Everything with the '$' symbol ($(document).ready(), $().on(click), etc.) requires jQuery to work. I just added jQuery to your latest Fiddle and ran it; works like a charm! (Sorry for missing that!)

Comment: Thanks, Lauren. Yes it now does work, but no longer performs the CSS concerning the two "@media only screen..." These should show or hide the message depending if the browser window is in portrait mode or not.

Comment: JS / jQuery is going to override your CSS styles. In that case, you might be better off doing an .addClass instead of .show()/.hide(); Based on the sessionStorage variable, you can add a "hidden-modal" or "shown-modal" class, and then just target .hidden-modal (which will be display: none; on all screen sizes) and .shown-modal (which will be display: none; on landscape screens, and display: block; elsewhere). Just make sure when the user clicks the Landscape button that you add the hidden-modal class AND remove the shown-modal class.

Comment: It seem this line, $("#warning-message").show(); {,  needs some sort of adaptation, making it only show the #warning-message when the browser window is in portrait mode.

Comment: That's the line I mean. Instead of .show(); you'll want to use .addClass("shown-modal"); Then you can target the .shown-modal (which will be applied to the same div as #warning-message) in your CSS. Where you're currently targeting #warning-message, you'll target .shown-modal instead. Instead of .hide() on line 8, you'll use .removeClass("shown-modal"). https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp

Comment: Thanks, Lauren. Wonder also if the "extra code" in this fiddle  ( https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/22/ ) could be somehow combined with the your code to take into account the orientation of the window.

Comment: It's possible, though you'd have to take a lot into account. 1 - screen size. (Can this happen on all screens? Desktop only? Mobile only?) 2 - screen orientation. (your width vs height check) 3 - Is the popup currently open? If so, does the new screen size warrant closing it? And if so, will re-sizing the screen larger re-open the modal? Short answer - it's definitely possible, but using CSS / addClass / removeClass will most likely be a lot easier. (Not to mention site speed benefits of limiting JS as much as possible.) Is there a specific reason you want to control this all through JS?

Comment: No no specific reason just thought it may be easier, not harder. I will work on your way. Thanks!!

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, sorry: https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/30/

Comment: Just one thing - you close your if() { } statement twice. One closing bracket on line 6, one on line 7. Besides that, it should work.

Comment: changed that, thanks Lauren, but still the warning-message never appears, not even when the window is sized down to portrait size.

Comment: I have taken #warning-message {display: none;} out of the CSS and this seemed to make it work, see https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/34/  But it does something strange now: when I click the button to hide the message it works, but when I refresh/reload the page, (so staying in the same session) the message reappears, and it shouldn't within the same session. Also when the message reappears after refresh/reload of the page, the message in visible not only in portrait mode but in landscape mode too now.

Comment: #warning-message {display: none;} should be located in the CSS. Did you have it below the media-query styles for .shown-modal? If so, it should be reversed. #warning-message {display: none;} set first, then below that, media queries to override the display: none, if the .shown-modal class is printed. If you absolutely can't make this work, add in an .addClass('hidden-modal') for when the sessionStorage is already set, and make .hidden-modal {display: none;}

Comment: adding $("#warning-message").hide(); to the "else statement" made it work without adding #warning-message {display: none;} to the CSS:   https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/45/ Or is this a bad way of doing it?

Comment: using hidden-modal works fine too: see here https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/46/ Ofcourse adding this into the CSS (above the media queries): .shown-modal {
        display: none;
    }
 
.hidden-modal {
        display: none;
    }